# Android SDK : Broadcastreceiver Intentservice and configuration changes

Tags: android, sdk, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am using a broadcastreceiver to listen for an intentservice which is set off via an onclick method. This is all fine but if the screen is rotated, I have had to put an unregister in the onPause (I have also tried this in onDestory) method and then in the onResume I re-register the broadcastreceiver.

My problem is, during the time of the broadcastreceiver being unregistered/registered the intentservice can send its broadcast back to say its done and then this means that the broadcastreceiver is still sitting there waiting for something that has already happened.

I have tried to use a sleep in the intentservice before the broadcast but this is by no means full proof as if the device is rotated again there is a timing issue.

I start and register the intent service and broadcastreceiver from the onClick as follows :

```
Intent intentMyIntentService = new Intent(myclass.this,myservice.class);
startService(intentMyIntentService);


mybroadcastreciver = new br();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(myservice.ACTION_ServiceE);
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
registerReceiver(mybroadcastreciver, intentFilter);
```

I the br method is the broadcastreceiver which as its onReceive method and I handle the configuration change with the onSaveInstanceState method and then check in the onCreate to see if the Bundle != null to then retrieve the Boolean which are set depending whether the intentservice is complete using the broadcast that it sends to the receiver.

This does all work if the screen is not rotated. However I know there are other ways to handle screen rotation but I am writing an app to work from API 8 to 17 .

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

One way is to maintain the same `BroadcastReceiver` object across screen orientation change:

1) Return the `BroadcastReceiver` object in `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

2) Fetch it in `Activity.onCreate()` using `(BroadCastReceiver) getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. It returns `null` if not saved.

3) In `onClick()`, only create the `BroadcastReceiver` object if it's not obtained in `Activity.onCreate()`.

Comment: I thought this method: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() is depreciated now. Also I think I may have solved it. As I am testing across these versions of Android, API appears not to like intent.getAction == myservice.ACTION within the onReceive. However I need to test this on a later API

Comment: @TimCS It's deprecated because of the introduction of `Fragment`s. Or if you're using `Fragment`s from the support package, you can also use e.g. `Fragment.setRetainInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks @xizzhu so would that mean it would still work across all API versions ? So far I have not had an issue with the way it is working BUT if I do struggle , then I will consider you suggestion/answer.

Comment: Reading up on this via Google Androids pages it states the following :Caution: While you can return any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do, it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory can be lost.)
would this include a broadcastreceiver as the onReceive is linked to a context

Comment: @TimCS 1) The support package works for Android 1.6 and above. 2) `BroadcastReceiver` is NOT associated with the "hosting" `Activity`, the `Context` passed in `onReceive()` is basically the context in which the receiver is running. The warning basically means that you should never return a pointer to the "hosting" `Activity`, and nothing associated with that `Activity` should be used after orientation change.